# CycloneDX Exclude Python Dev/Test Dependencies

Tags: python, external-dependencies

I was trying to figure out without success how I could exclude the dev/test dependencies of 3rd party Python modules from the BOM generated by CycloneDX. There seems to be no straightforward way to do this. Any recommendation on how to best approach this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not supported currently. But would make a great issue :)